# UI thread stuck in android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative

Tags: android

In my Android app I have many ANR occurences. I have setup a [watchdog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog) to trigger crash reports before the ANR occur and analyze the threads' stack traces.

In almost every case the UI thread isn't stuck in my app's code, but on `android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative()`.

How can I investigate the cause of these ANRs ? Is there anything I can do to reduce the number of occurences ?